# How to start Rails from a shell script on Debian?

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, boot, shell-scripting, rvm

I don't really have any need to mess with passenger or capistrano at the moment. I simply want to run rails on boot on port 3000. I've attempted to replicate [this tutorial for node](http://labs.telasocial.com/nodejs-forever-daemon/) as much as I could to run rails:

I've a `railsup` script in `/etc/init.d/` that goes something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

case "$1" in
  start)
   cd /root/rails_app; /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails server -d -p 3005
  ;;
  # starting other stuff
*)
```

I've also included it with `update-rc.d`

I got it to work, but only if I run the script manually - it doesn't seem to run on boot. Is there any reason why `../bin/rails` is unavailable on boot?

I imagine there's something about ruby path \ rvm \ rails that I'm unaware of? Is there a way to use crontab's @reboot for this?

Comment: http://rvm.io/integration/init-d

Comment: What's answer of `update-rc.d` when you run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `init.d`

Whith new System-V parallelisation system, you **have** to add a *INIT INFO* part at top of your script.

Have a look at `/etc/init.d/README` and try to add this at top of your script:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rails
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:
# X-Start-Before:    rmnologin
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Start Rails on port 3000
### END INIT INFO
```

#### Using `cron` (and run as your own user)

You could run your *daemon* on each reboot with specific `cron` syntax:

```
crontab -l |
   sed '$a@reboot /usr/bin/rail-or-other-bin -arg1 -arg2 -port 3000' |
   crontab
```

**Warning** running this command (`crontab` with no argument and stdin from pipe) will alter your `crontab`! See `man crontab`!

... and try this without the last `crontab` before:

```
crontab -l |
   sed '$a@reboot /usr/bin/rail-or-other-bin -arg1 -arg2 -port 3000'
```

The advantage of this is that daemon is run in userland and run errors will be sent to you as mail by normal cron way.

Answer (score 0):

Is the script running at all?
I'd try adding:

```
echo RAILSUP >/tmp/railsup.log
```

If it really is, have you checked the logs to see what the error is while trying to run on boot?
Personally, I'd run that under strace and log all actions to a file to examine once you can log in. It will probably provide some clue.

Answer (score -1):

it really is, have you checked the logs to see what the error is while trying to run on boot? Personally, I'd run that under strace and log all actions to a file to examine once you can log in. It will probably provide some clue.

Comment: This sounds like more of a comment